# Как реализовать клик по фрейму?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Сделать клик по координатам - не проблема, но вот с фреймами не получается, как решить проблему?

Comment: @RomanAnanev, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с [Expert ♦♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/expert), для корректного ответа слишком мало входящей информации.

А если предположить, что вам во фрейме надо запилить какой-то js функционал, то, имхо, проще всего прописать в нем подключение нужного скрипта, и дальше уже он будет работать в области фрейма.